# Problem with logic gates in shapes.gates.logic tikzlibrary

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes, tikzlibrary

I've been using the `shapes.gates.logic` tikzlibrary to draw this logic circuit diagram, and I wondered if

1. There was any way to increase the vertical spacing between the inputs into the gates. You'll see A, and Vcc overlap because the inputs to the XOR gate are too close to each other.
2. If I connect the output of a gate to the input of another, I have to manually use `\draw (xor.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]xor.output) |- (nand.input 1);` (for example), to make sure that the wire doesn't drop down directly from the output of the gate. Is there a better way to automatically make the wires have a horizontal indentation from the output of a gate?
3. Is there any way to label node branches so that I can use them as coordinate references later?
4. Any general tips to shorten my code, and improve it will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

[image: My diagram]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=2mm]

\node (A) at (0, 0) {\small{A}};

\node (B) at (0, -1) {$B$};
\node (C) at (0, -2) {$C$};

\node[xor gate US, draw, anchor=input 1] at ($(A) + (2, 0)$) (xor1) {};
\node[xor gate US, draw, anchor=input 1] at ($(B) + (2, 0)$) (xor2) {};
\node[nand gate US, draw, anchor=input 1] at ($(xor1.output) + (2, -0.25)$) (nand1) {};
\node[nand gate US, draw, anchor=input 1] at ($(xor2.output) + (2, -0.25)$) (nand2) {};
\node[nand gate US, draw, anchor=input 2] at ($(nand2.output) + (2, 0)$) (nand3) {};
\node[xor gate US, draw, anchor=input 1] at ($(nand3.output) + (1, 0)$) (xor3) {};
\node[nand gate US, draw, anchor=input 1] at ($(C) + (2, -0.5)$) (nand4) {};
\node[nand gate US, draw, anchor=input 1] at ($(C) + (2, -1.5)$) (nand5) {};
\node[nand gate US, draw, anchor=input 1] at ($(C) + (2, -2.5)$) (nand6) {};
\node[nand gate US, draw, anchor=input 1] at ($(nand4.output) + (2, -0.5)$) (nand7) {};
\node[nand gate US, draw, anchor=input 2] at ($(nand7.output) + (2, -0)$) (nand8) {};
\node[nand gate US, draw, anchor=input 1] at ($(nand8.output) + (1, -1)$) (nand9) {};
\node (V) at ($(xor1.input 2) - (2, 0)$) {\small{$V_{cc}$}};

\node (D) at ($(xor3.output) + (1, 0)$) {D};
\node (E) at ($(nand9.output) + (1, 0)$) {E};


\draw (A) |- (xor1.input 1);
\draw (A) -- ($(A) + (1.5, 0)$) node[branch] {} -- ($(nand6.input 1) + (-0.5, 0)$) -- (nand6.input 1);
\draw ($(A) + (1.5, -1.5)$) node[branch] {} -- ($(nand2.input 2) + (-2, 0)$) -- (nand2.input 2);
\draw ($(nand4.input 1) - (0.5, 0)$) node[branch] {} -- (nand4.input 1);
\draw (V) -- (xor1.input 2);
\draw ($(V) + (1, 0)$) node[branch] {} -- ($(xor2.input 2) - (1, 0)$) -- (xor2.input 2);
\draw ($(xor2.input 2) - (1, 0)$) node[branch] {} -- ($(nand4.input 2) - (1, 0)$) -- (nand4.input 2);
\draw ($(nand4.input 2) - (1, 0)$) node[branch] {} -- ($(nand5.input 1) - (1,0)$) -- (nand5.input 1);
\draw (B) -- (xor2.input 1);
\draw ($(B) + (0.5, 0)$) node[branch] {} -- ($(nand1.input 2) - (4.23, 0)$) -- (nand1.input 2);

\draw (xor1.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]xor1.output) |- (nand1.input 1);
\draw (xor2.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]xor2.output) |- (nand2.input 1);
\draw (nand2.output) -- (nand3.input 2);
\draw (nand1.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]nand1.output) |- (nand3.input 1);
\draw (nand3.output) |- (xor3.input 1);
\draw (C) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]C) |- ([xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-0.5cm]xor3.input 2) |- (xor3.input 2);
\draw ($(C) + (7, 0)$) node[branch] {} |- (nand8.input 1);
\draw (nand7.output) |- (nand8.input 2);
\draw (nand4.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]nand4.output) |- (nand7.input 1);
\draw (nand5.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]nand5.output) |- (nand7.input 2);
\draw (nand8.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]nand8.output) |- (nand9.input 1);
\draw (nand6.output) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]nand6.output) |- (nand9.input 2);
\draw (xor3.output) -- (D);
\draw (nand9.output) -- (E);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. That is too many questions BTW. We appreciate one question per post here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Regarding #2, you can see in the manual (e.g. page 566 in the 3.0.0 manual) that a similar method to yours is used to produce the angled lines. So I don't think there's any way around that by default

Comment: Regarding #1, have a look at the `logic gate input sep` key on page 569 of the 3.0.0 manual.

Comment: @darthbith Thanks for that. It worked, and now the Vcc is separate. However, the gate itself increases in size. I was looking for only the input nodes to move away, but I don't think that's supported.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if shorter, but maybe you could find a matrix useful (example in [plain-tex](/questions/tagged/plain-tex)-format):

```
\input tikz

\newdimen\gatesep \gatesep=.8cm
\newdimen\inputsep \inputsep=.5ex

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US, matrix}

\tikzset{
  contact/.style={circle, fill=black, minimum size=2pt, inner sep=0pt}
  % ^ the name is already defined in circuits.ee
}

\tikzpicture[circuit logic US, logic gate input sep=\inputsep]
  \matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=2\gatesep] (circuit) {
    |[xor gate, name=xor1]| \\
      & |[nand gate, name=nand1]| \\
    |[xor gate, name=xor2]| && |[nand gate, name=nand2]| \\
      & |[nand gate, name=nand3]| && |[xor gate, name=xor3]| \\
    |[coordinate]| \\[2em]
    |[nand gate, name=nand4]| \\
      & |[nand gate, name=nand5]| & |[nand gate, name=nand6, yshift=1em]| \\
    |[nand gate, name=nand7]| \\
      &&& |[nand gate, name=nand8]| \\
    |[nand gate, name=nand9]| \\
  };
  \draw (xor1.output) -- ++(right:\gatesep) node[right] {$f_1$} |- (nand1.input 1);
  \draw (xor1.input 1) -- ++(left:2\gatesep)
    node[contact, near start] (A split) {}
    node[left, yshift=2\inputsep] (A) {$A$};
  \draw (xor1.input 2) -- ++(left:2\gatesep)
    node[contact, midway] (Vcc split) {}
    node[left, yshift=-2\inputsep] (Vcc) {$V_{cc}$};
  %
  \draw (xor2.input 1) -- ++(left:2\gatesep)
    node[contact, near end] (B split) {}
    node[left] (B) {$B$};
  \draw (B split) |- (nand1.input 2);
  \draw (Vcc split) |- (nand7.input 1);
  \draw (A split) |- (nand9.input 1);
  \draw (xor1.input 2) -- (Vcc split |- xor1.input 2) node[contact] {};
  \draw (xor2.output) -- ++(right:\gatesep)
    node[right] {$f_2$} |- (nand3.input 1);
  \draw (xor3.input 2) -- ++(left:\gatesep)
    |- ([xshift=-2.5\gatesep, yshift=-1em]circuit-5-1)
    node[left] (C) {$C$};
  \draw (nand3.input 2) -- (A split |- nand3.input 2) node[contact] {};
  \draw (nand4.input 1) -- (A split |- nand4.input 1) node[contact] {};
  \draw (nand4.input 2) -- (Vcc split |- nand4.input 2) node[contact] {};
  \draw (nand1.output) -- ++(right:\gatesep) |- (nand2.input 1);
  \draw (nand3.output) -- ++(right:\gatesep) |- (nand2.input 2);
  \draw (xor3.input 1) -- ++(left:\gatesep) |- (nand2.output);
  \draw (nand4.output) -- ++(right:\gatesep) |- (nand5.input 1);
  \draw (nand5.output) -- ++(right:\gatesep) |- (nand6.input 2);
  % etc.
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

[image]